# React-Native Webview With audio-player it's possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm just starting with React-Native. do i need to play a song inside one in a webview and be able to control it when the screen is locked by running stop / play?

Does anyone have any ideas / worked on this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

We have a React Native app where users can edit their profile via a Webview. 
Profiles include a media section with a custom-built audio player which uses Web Audio API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API). All controllers including play and stop are working as expected.

On the other hand, I don't think you can control the Webview when the screen is locked but this part is totally untested. You will probably need to use a React Native audio player to achieve this.